# C#: Inserting text in a RichTextBox causes the formatting to be lost

Tags: c#, formatting, insert, richtextbox

I am trying to insert text at runtime in a RichTextBox, but when I do so, all the formatting that was previously present is lost.

From what I understand, the formatting is lost because I'm overwriting the "Text" property of the RichTextBox when my **KeyPress** event is called:

```
(...)
Text = Text.Insert(SelectionStart, MyText);
e.Handled = true;
```

On a side-note, my RichTextBox's height is calculated at run-time depending on its content.

I am forced to **insert** text in the RTB, or else the content would not be properly displayed following its resizing (i.e: For some reason, the first line of the RTB would appear to have scrolled up and can only be seen once the control has lost focus... See: [C#: How to prevent a textbox' content from being scrolled up on Enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314995/c-how-to-prevent-a-textbox-content-from-being-scrolled-up-on-enter)).

Is there any way to insert text in a RichTextBox, while also keeping all the previous formatting intact ?

Thanks, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am currently using WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) instead, followed by [ScrollToCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but I still had the weird "scroll up" bug that occured when resizing my RTB's height. Basically, adding text other than using the "Insert(...)" method results in the first line of the RTB being scrolled up out of view unless I lose focus on the control.

Comment: You can't re-scroll it back down after?

Comment: I can re-scroll it back down manually, but not programmatically. The users were complaining about having to do it manually, hence why I'm trying to figure out a way to do it directly at run-time.

Comment: Sure, use ScrollToCaret: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it works the second time it's called but not the first for some reason... Still, better than nothing :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is caused by complete text reset (`Text = ...`). Try using something like:

```
SelectionLength = 0; // not sure about this one
SelectedText = MyText;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SelectedText and AppendText does work like you and Mike suggested, but for some reason every time the lenght of the line exceeds the RTB's width, an additional new line (i.e.: \r\n) is added automatically in the RTF content, causing the first line to disappear.

Comment: `Due to some reason`? Doesn it happen when you're adding a text into richTextBox in regular way, not programmatically? I believe this is completely different issue.

Comment: Yes, it also happens when adding it in regular way. And it is a different issue as you mentionned, so I'll be marking your answer and Mike's as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Hussein, checkout this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap.aspx

Comment: Thanks Snowbear, I tried disabling the wordwrapping, but that made the textbox work improperly (i.e.: i'd end up with only one line).